# Script for getting posts with unique role

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a script which will show all messages owned by ONLY users with `RoleID = 4`. So I tried to write something like this:

```
SELECT DT.DiscussionThreadID, DT.Message FROM DiscussionThread DT
INNER JOIN Users U on U.UserID = DT.CreatedBy
INNER JOIN UserRoles UR on UR.UserID = U.RoleID
WHERE UR.RoleID = 4
```

Example of UserRoles table:

```
UserID     RoleID
1          1
1          2
1          4
2          4
3          3
3          4
```

I expected to see only messages posted by user with `UserID = 2` - he don't have additional roles except of `RoleID = 4`. But my script returns all posts. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DT.DiscussionThreadID, DT.Message
FROM DiscussionThread DT
INNER JOIN Users U on U.UserID = DT.CreatedBy
INNER JOIN UserRoles UR on UR.RoleID = U.RoleID
group by DT.DiscussionThreadID, DT.Message
having count(Distinct roleID) = 1
and max(roleID)=4
```

Comment: well, it looks working, but how do you think - this is the best performance which I could have?

Comment: you could try an `except` query - ie: `select ... where roleid=4 except select ... where roleid<>4` but I doubt you'd see much if any performance increase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want better performance, do the role check before the join to DiscussionThread.  You can also dispense with the users table, since fields from the table are not being used:

```
SELECT DT.DiscussionThreadID, DT.Message
FROM DiscussionThread DT inner join
     (select userId
      from UserRoles UR
      group by userId
      having COUNT(distinct roleId) = 1) and max(roleId) = 4
     ) ur
     on UR.UserID = U.UserID
group by DT.DiscussionThreadID, DT.Message
```